# While using detectDuplicate i am getting an error

Tags: python, apache-nifi, nipyapi

Error in detectDuplicate

While using detectDuplicate i am getting an error. What is the missing point i have made here?

[detectDuplicateErrorinApacheNifiDesign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFQ9K.png)

Answer (score 0):

Enable your Distributed Cache Service controller.
Click on right arrow inside your processor configuration then enable it.

Answer (score 0):

[AddingControllerScript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/if6Yp.png)

How to fix this error i am writing this to built controller for apache nifi